# See Capistrano previous revision timestamp

Tags: version-control, capistrano

How do I check the timestamps on my recent Capistrano revisions (deployments)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to *add* that information at deployment time.
This [2009 blog post](http://petersteinberger.com/2009/07/add-a-version-timestamp-with-capistrano/) suggested:

```
#############################################################
#   Custom Tasks
#############################################################

set :version_file, "#{tcdb_path}/app/views/layouts/_version.html.erb"

namespace :my_tasks do
desc "Sets the timestamp in version_file"
task :set_version_info do
run "rm #{version_file}"
run "echo '#{Time.now}' &gt;&gt; #{version_file}"
end
end

after 'deploy:symlink', 'my_tasks:set_version_info'
```

And then:

> add this file to your layout (the footer is a good place for it)

```
< %= render :partial => '/layouts/version' %>
```